# How to use composer included items?

Tags: composer-php

In my composer.json file I added `"kigkonsult/icalcreator": "v2.23.7"` to the required list, and after doing the install I see that directory in existence under the `vendor` dir.  I can't figure out how to "use" it though in my PHP files in this project.

If I weren't using composer I'd just require the icalcreator.php file in that area.  What's the right syntax when I include it via composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the package is installed you need to add the composer autoloader somewhere in your project.

```
require_once('/path/to/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Normally Composer uses [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), but it looks like this package doesn't. It just adds it's own autoloader to composer so just including the Composer loader should be sufficient.

Once the autoloader is added you can just use the package however you need. Composer will automatically register the packages custom autoloader and PHP will use that to load the appropriate file.